# Performing GridSearchCV on RandomForestClassifier yields lower accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to increase the performance of a RandomForestClassifier that categorises negative and positive reviews using GridSearchCV but it seems that the accuracy is always around 10% lower than the base algorithm. Why is this? Please find my code below:

Base algorithm with 90% accuracy:

```
algo_base = RandomForestClassifier()
algo_base.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

GridSearchCV algorithm with 80% accuracy:

```
param_grid = {
    'criterion':['gini', 'entropy'],
    'max_depth':[5, 10, 15],
    'n_estimators':[150, 200, 250, 300]
}

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)

CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator = rfc, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=4)

CV_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values of the baseline model is different from the ones given in the grid search.
for example The default value of n_estimators is 100.
Take a look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

Comment: You havent included the link

Comment: Fixed and it could be that the you don't have the right amount of data since you specified a 10   folds for cross validation.Try to change it and see the resulat.